# Updating column based on other two tables

Tags: sql, sql-update, monetdb

I have the following three tables as follows,

```
select * from student_grade;
+--------------+----------+----------+-------+--------------------------+
| enrollmentid | courseid | personid | grade | credits_earned           |
+==============+==========+==========+=======+==========================+
|            1 |     1001 |        1 | A     |                     null |
|            2 |     1002 |        1 | B     |                     null |
|            3 |     1003 |        1 | A     |                     null |
|            4 |     3001 |        3 | A     |                     null |
|            5 |     3001 |        2 | B     |                     null |
|            6 |     4001 |        4 | A     |                     null |
|            7 |     4002 |        4 | A     |                     null |
+--------------+----------+----------+-------+--------------------------+
7 tuples
sql>select * from course;
+----------+-------------------+---------+--------------+
| courseid | title             | credits | departmentid |
+==========+===================+=========+==============+
|     1001 | Data structures   |      12 |          101 |
|     1002 | Algorithms        |      12 |          101 |
|     1003 | Graphics          |      20 |          101 |
|     2001 | DSP               |      20 |          102 |
|     2002 | Matlab            |      20 |          102 |
|     2003 | Maths             |      10 |          102 |
|     3001 | CAD               |      10 |          104 |
|     4001 | Power electronics |      10 |          103 |
|     4002 | Semi conductors   |      20 |          103 |
+----------+-------------------+---------+--------------+
9 tuples
sql>select * from grade_to_credits;
+-----------+--------------------------+
| gradechar | credits                  |
+===========+==========================+
| A         |                        1 |
| B         |                      0.9 |
+-----------+--------------------------+
```

What I am trying to do is:
 I am updating the `credits_earned` column of `student_grade` table using the columns of `credits` of `course` table and `credits` of `grade_to_credits` table.

just like this,

```
select c.credits * gc.credits 
from course c, grade_to_credits gc, student_grade sg 
where sg.courseid = c.courseid and sg.grade = gc.gradechar;
+--------------------------+
| L2                       |
+==========================+
|                       12 |
|                     10.8 |
|                       20 |
|                       10 |
|                        9 |
|                       10 |
|                       20 |
+--------------------------+
```

I am getting the above values when I execute separately, but now I want to update these values in `student_grade` table using **update** query.

Now I am using the query as:

```
update student_grade 
set credits_earned = (select c.credits * gc.credits 
                      from course c, grade_to_credits gc, student_grade sg 
                      where sg.courseid = c.courseid 
                        and sg.grade = gc.gradechar);
```

But the above query is not working, I am getting error as:

> Cardinality violation, scalar value expected

I know, I can individually set the values, but I wanna do it from update command.
Please correct me where I am going wrong.

Comment: your subquery to get credits_earned must return only one row. I believe it is returning multiple rows.

Comment: yes, it is returning multiple rows, Cant we iterate for each row while setting the value?

Comment: check my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52232879/2469308
 If it works for you, please upvote and accept it as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to overcomplicate things use `LEFT JOIN` to achive the result. Set operation are usually more efficient than row by row operation.

```
update student_grade 
SET  credits_earned = a.credits_earned
from (
select  s.enrollmentid,
        s.courseid,
        s.personid,
        s.grade,
        (g.credits * c.credits) as credits_earned
from student_grade s
LEFT OUTER JOIN @grade_to_credits g ON g.gradechar = s.grade
LEFT OUTER JOIN @course c           ON c.courseid  = s.courseid 
) as a
where student_grade.enrollmentid = a.enrollmentid
```

Result:

```
1   1001    1   A   12
2   1002    1   B   10,8
3   1003    1   A   20
4   3001    3   A   10
5   3001    2   B   9
6   4001    4   A   10
7   4002    4   A   20
```

Comment: But it is not updating the table

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** The solution below works in MySQL. (OP later retagged/changed question from MySQL to MonetDB)

- Problem with your attempt is that the inner subquery is returning more than one rows.
- Even if it returns only one row, another issue with it would be updating all the `credits_earned` field in the table `student_grade` with the same value (output of the inner subquery).
- You should avoid using Implicit joins. They are old and not a good practice.

You should rather [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) these tables, and then use the
   joined tables' columns to update rowwise data. Try the following:

```
update student_grade sg 
inner join course  c on c.courseid = sg.courseid 
inner join grade_to_credits gc on gc.gradechar = sg.grade 
set sg.credits_earned = c.credits * gc.credits;
```

Comment: getting the error as :    syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting SET in: "update student_grade sg"

Comment: @Anil typo was there. i have fixed it please check again. hope you rectify your downvote also. it was a mere typo!

Comment: still getting the same error, can you please tell me the typo?

Comment: @Anil there was `on` twice in the second inner join. i just removed the one of the  `on`

Comment: UPDATE student_grade sg inner join course c on c.courseid = sg.courseid inner join grade_to_credits gc on gc.gradechar = sg.grade set sg.credits_earned = c.credits * gc.credits;

Comment: it is giving the error for the above query as well, where it is not having on on .

Comment: @Anil what is the error ? please give the complete error message here.

Comment: UPDATE student_grade sg inner join course c on c.courseid = sg.courseid inner join grade_to_credits gc on gc.gradechar = sg.grade set sg.credits_earned = c.credits * gc.credits;
syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting SET in: "update student_grade sg"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179670/discussion-between-anil-and-madhur-bhaiya).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need to remove `student_grade` from the subquery:

```
update student_grade st
    set credits_earned = (select sc.credits * gc.credits
                          from course c cross join
                               grade_to_credits gc
                          where sg.courseid = c.courseid and
                                sg.grade = gc.gradechar
                         );
```